# Render row data in react-datatable

Tags: reactjs, datatable

In my class where in rows the data is loaded but I don't know how to render the data in the table.Headers are being displayed properly.Table rows data needs to be fetched.

How to render cell values in a row?

```
<ReactTable
          columns={this.headers()}
          rows={this.createRows()}
          render={({rows,columns}) =>(
            {rows.map((row,i)=>(
              <tr key={row.id}
              {cell.value}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you provide the functions that youre calling too so we can have a bettr idea of where there error might be